# Update gitmodule

Tags: git, github

From [ffmpeg-android](https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android), I find the repo depends on ffmpeg repo. I find the version of `ffmpeg` is `3.0.1`.

I have tried to edit `.gitmodules`.

```
[submodule "ffmpeg"]
    path = ffmpeg
    url = https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg.git
    branch = release/3.4
[submodule "x264"]
    path = x264
    url = git://git.videolan.org/x264.git
[submodule "freetype2"]
    path = freetype2
    url = git://git.sv.nongnu.org/freetype/freetype2.git
[submodule "libass"]
    path = libass
    url = https://github.com/libass/libass.git
[submodule "fontconfig"]
    path = fontconfig
    url = git://anongit.freedesktop.org/fontconfig
```

As you see, I add `branch = release/3.4`.

So I have two questions.

- How `3.0.1` version set?
- How to change the version to `3.4.2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I explained in "[Git submodules: Specify a branch/tag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18799234/6309)", you can use a `git config` command to edit the `.gitmodules` file.

```
git config -f .gitmodules submodule.<path>.branch <branch>
```

But then, don't forget to do:

```
git submodule update --remote
```

That will update the submodules content to the latest of their assigned branch.

> How 3.0.1 version set?

A submodule is a way to record a SHA1 in the parent repo. If that SHA1 is the commit tagged 3.0.1, that is a way for a parent repo to reference the 3.0.1 tag of a submodule.